# Scala JSON error handling and responses

Tags: scala, error-handling, lift

I use Scala + Lift Web Framework + MongoDB for a bunch of applications. In some instances, I need to respond with a JSON error message to the client making the request to display an internationalized error message.

An error message will generally be a simple JSON:

```
val errorMessage = ("error" -> "some error message");
```

This message would then be served via `net.liftweb.rest.RestHelper` with `yield requestParam: JValue`. I use `for comprehensions` to check for errors and return these `JValue`s.

What is the best practice to store these messages in Scala(with internationalization in mind)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, doesn't the principle "let the developer decide" apply?
I mean, AFAIK, there is no central way to do that. Do any way you want. For example, 
`(S ? "error") -> (S ? "my.error.reason123")`

Comment: Why? I think I answered... You can do any way you want. The most popular I've seen is to use Lift's internationalization through S. So, as I said, (S ? "my.custom.error"). And actual translations are stored, for example, in src/main/webapp/templates-hidden/_resources_pl.html (for polish)